# Android Emulator with HAX: How to access recent Apps list with Android 5?

Tags: android, emulation, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recents

Can anybody please give me a hint how to access the recent apps list on the Android Emulator running the Intel Atom Image of Android 5 using HAX.

Formerly, it was easy just pressing the home button for a long time. However, with this Android 5 image the recent apps list just doesn't show up.

There must be an easy way to access the recent apps list on the emulator. Ijust have no idea where to search for it.

Thanx a lot!

Felix

Comment: I gave up trying to fix this problem, ended up putting `hw.mainKeys=no` into all of my emulator `config.ini` files

Answer (score -1):

On Lollipop, the recent apps list is brought up by pressing the button to the right of the Home button.